# Image thumbnail not working

Tags: jquery, thumbnails

I want that when a user uploads an image, he should get to see the thumbnail of it before it uploads to the server. Therefor I have been trying this simple thumbnail thing from [here](http://demo.phpgang.com/jquery-show-image-thumbnail-before-upload/) but it is not working at all.

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <style>
  #imagePreview {
width: 180px;
height: 180px;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
display: inline-block;
}
</style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
$("#uploadFile").on("change", function()
{
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected,

    if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
        var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

        reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
            $("#imagePreview").css("background-image", "url("+this.result+")");
        }
    }
    });
 });
   </script>

    <div id="imagePreview"></div>
        <input id="uploadFile" type="file" name="image" class="img" />
```

Comment: You need to be more specific on what you want, what you tried and what the problem is.

Comment: edited with what I want @Baszz

Comment: what error are you getting ? if any  ? or what is the problem with your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works great for me:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="imagePreview"></div>
<input id="uploadFile" type="file" name="image" class="img" />
```

**CSS:**

```
#imagePreview {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Javascript (you need jquery):**

```
$(function() {
    $("#uploadFile").on("change", function()
    {
        var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
        if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

        if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
            var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

            reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
                $("#imagePreview").css("background-image", "url("+this.result+")");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dm1j2pef/)